# Form com dois destinos

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, razor

Tenho o seguinte formulário:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("minhaAction", "meuController", new AjaxOptions()
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnFailure = "alert('Erro!')",
        OnSuccess = "TrabalharResultado"

    }, new { id = "meuForm" } ))
{
...
...
...
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="btn-Enviar" />
<input onclick="enviarForm" type="button" value="Enviar Outro Action" id="btn-Enviar2" />
}
```

Ao clicar no botão `btn-Enviar` todo o `form` é enviado `minhaAction` em `meuController`.
Meu objetivo é que ao clicar no botão `btn-Enviar2`, esse mesmo `form` seja enviado para `outraAction` em `meuController`, então lá eu poderia receber a mesma `FormCollection`.

Como eu poderia fazer a `function enviarForm`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você poderia setar 2 values com o mesmo name para cada button

```
<button type="submit"name="minhaaction" value="Action 1">
<button type="submit"name="minhaaction" value="Action 2">
```

e em sua Action, realizar a verificação para cada um dos casos

```
public ActionResult MinhaAction(string minhaaction)
{
   if(minhaaction == "Action 1") { 
     //realiza action 1
   }else {
    //Realiza action 2
   }
}
```

Comment: @bigown sobre db? eu publiquei novamente, acabei publicando 2 vezes, então eu deletei uma, desculpe...poderia responder sim, obrigado